# Pharo: how to make Cmd+d ("do it") execute the whole multi-line statement by default instead of just the current line

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Suppose I have a multi-line statement like this:

```
1 to: 5 do: [:i|
  Transcript show: i.
  Transcript cr].
```

Currently, when I put a text cursor on some line (without selecting anything) and press Cmd+d, Pharo tries to execute the current line. But it would be more convenient for me if by default (when nothing is selected) Pharo would execute the current statement (i.e. all this three-line statement), not just the current line. Because this is a much more frequent case ("I want to execute the whole statement") than "I want to execute this particular line inside a statement" (which in most cases just doesn't make sense syntactically, as 1st and 3rd lines here). And in these rear occasions (when I need to execute a line inside a statement) I would pre-select this line manually.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Grigory, for me, it often makes sense to just execute the current line. For example, when stepping through the execution in the debugger, I often inspect the line befor I do a step. And for this it is useful to not select the line manually. Or if you have a longer script, and want to execute and inspect this line-by-line.

Comment: @NicolaiHess I concur. Note however that the algorithm I sketched in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40071982/4081336) will start with the current line and will only add more lines if the current line does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Take a look at the text component. It has some method for evaluate-selection-and-do. And if nothing is selected, it tries to select the current line.
You may change this implementation to find the top most statement "scope".
It could be possible if you work with the code AST instead of the text. I worked once with this, to make it smarter for code expressions inside of comments.(that didn't work for all situations because the context for getting the method AST isn't always the same for this text component,in different tools (browser/workspace/and other))

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea for an algorithm. You will need to improve and complete it.

Define a class `ExpressionFinder` for finding the proper expression in your text.

In my sketch this class has the following ivars

- `string`:
    the complete string in your pane (playground/transcript/whatever)
- `compiler`:
    the compiler used by your pane to evaluate text
- `lines`: the collection of associations `pos->line`, where `pos` is the position of the `line` inside `string`
- `index`: current index to the `lines` collection used by the algorithm
- `interval`: the output interval if any, otherwise `nil`

Assume you are given the `string`, the `compiler` and the current `position` of the cursor on `string`. Do the following:

```
string: aString position: anInteger compiler: aCompiler
  string := aString.
  compiler := aCompiler.
  self computeLines.
  index := lines findLast: [:assoc | assoc key <= anInteger]
```

Here is how you compute the collection of lines:

```
computeLines
  | reader |
  lines := OrderedCollection new.
  reader := string readStream.
  [reader atEnd]
    whileFalse: [lines add: reader position + 1 -> reader nextLine]
```

With all of this you have everything you need to find the appropriate fragment. Here is a simple idea (which you should improve):

*Start at the current line index and find the fragment by adding a line at a time. If found, end. If not, decrease the index and try again from the line above.*

Here is the code

```
find
  | i |
  i := index.
  [
    i <= 0 ifTrue: [^self].
    assoc := lines at: i.
    self findFrom: assoc key]
    whileFalse: [i := i - 1]
```

where

```
findFrom: start
  | i end success |
  i := index.
  [| assoc fragment |
    assoc := lines at: i + 1 ifAbsent: [string size + 1 -> nil]. 
    end := assoc key - 1.
    fragment := string copyFrom: start to: end.
    success := self canCompile: fragment.
    success not and: [end < string size]]
    whileTrue: [i := i + 1].
  success ifTrue: [interval := start to: end].
  ^success
```

The code for `canCompile: fragment` is dialect-dependent, on the lines of

```
canCompile: fragment
  ^(compiler compileExpression: fragment) notNil
```

If your compiler signals `CompilationErrors`, you will need to put a handler in `canCompile:` to avoid them. Also you might take advantage of such errors. For instance, if the compilation error refers to an undeclared variable, you know that you will not find its definition in the lines below, so you should exit the loop in `findFrom:` so to try with the line above and so on.